# Is it possible to install rocket.chat on shared server?

Tags: meteor, shared-hosting, rocket.chat

I tried to install rocket.chat on my shared hosting from godaddy, using ssh. But there were few permission erros. Is it possible to install without sudo access?
[image: while I tried to install dependencies] using
cd $HOME/rocketchat/bundle/programs/server
$HOME/meteor/dev_bundle/bin/npm install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is in this line:

```
sh: nodejs: command not found
```

This means that nodejs isn't installed on the server. You can ask your hosting provider to install it, but they probably won't. You have a better chance of success looking for a hosting provider that is more nodejs/meteor friendly, such as Digital Ocean, AWS, etc. There are many out there.